# Why UITableView sectionFooterView is floating at the bottom of screen,rather than attached to the bottom of the section group?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When I build applications using XCode9.1 encountered such a strange problem.
I am trying to run in the simulator(iOS 11 and iOS 10),but the result is the same.
[image]

Here is the some code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

UITableView *mainTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
mainTableView.dataSource = self;
mainTableView.delegate = self;
mainTableView.rowHeight = 52.f;
[mainTableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
[self.view addSubview:mainTableView];
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
headerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), 270);
mainTableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;

}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return 15.f;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return 15.f;
}
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Header section==%ld",section];
return [self createViewWithTitle:text];
}
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Footer section==%ld",section];
return [self createViewWithTitle:text];
}
- (UIView *)createViewWithTitle:(NSString *)title {
UIView *view = [UIView new];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 15);
label.text = title;
[view addSubview:label];
return view;
}
```

Comment: try Setting the table view style to UITableViewStyleGrouped

Comment: Thanks.What you say is a solution.But the problem I want to figure out is why footerView is floating at the bottom of screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working as intended, both `header` and `footer section views` are attached to top and bottom of `table view` when you scrolling inside respective sections.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep the footer as section footer. Then it will behave the way you have mentioned which is not a bug. In case if you want the footer to be attached at the bottom of the screen, you can use tableFooterView property of tableview and assign as footer view to it.

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"FooterView" bundle:nil] forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:@"FooterView"];
FooterView *footerView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FooterView" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
footerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

// Assigning the footer view to table footer view property
self.infoTableView.tableFooterView = footerView;
```